# Original image size in sorl-thumbnail

Tags: python, django, thumbnails, sorl-thumbnail

I installed sorl-thumbnail to have a small thumbnail pictures in the gallery (in my django project - django-1.8). But the images are the same size as the original.

**Code in template**

```py
            {% for image in gallery %}
                {{ image.title }} <br>
                {% thumbnail image "100x100" as im %}
                    <img src="{{ image.paint.url }}" width="{{ image.width }}" height="{{ image.height }}"><br>
                {% endthumbnail %}
                {{ image.status }}<br>
                {{ image.price }}<br>
            {% endfor %}
```

**My model**

```py
    class Paint(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery)
        paint = ImageField(upload_to='paint/%Y/%m/%d')
        price = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
        status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_PAINT, default=AVAILABLE, max_length=50)

        class Meta:
            verbose_name = "Picture"
            verbose_name_plural = "Images"

        def __unicode__(self):
            return "{}".format(self.title)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `im` thumbnail instead of the original `image`:

```
<img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
```

Comment: I changed code and I get: `[21/Apr/2015 15:06:01]"GET /media/cache/65/bf/65bf355e8d28a891272d89738b60c6b7.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1905
[21/Apr/2015 15:06:01]"GET /media/cache/df/50/df5081acc1ea85d9399faae408dbc9a1.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1905
[21/Apr/2015 15:06:01]"GET /media/cache/32/26/3226da140f636d6973937dfd07d63878.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1905
[21/Apr/2015 15:06:01]"GET /media/cache/0a/13/0a13b0f59675d4bb1de6000ff2e50cb9.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1905
[21/Apr/2015 15:06:01]"GET /media/cache/54/4a/544a3b2cce7a514e36473eb3e543c488.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1905
`

Comment: By default `sorl-thumbnail` saves thumbnails in the `cache` subdirectory of the media root.  So it works fine.  Check the serving of your media files.